# Advanced DataGrid Vs DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Can any one explain the difference between Advanced DataGrid and DataGrid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the AdvancedDataGrid allows you to have a navigation tree control in addition to the normal columns you get in a plain DataGrid. That is, it can display hierarchical data. That is the main reason personally use it for.

Also, you can group columns under each other so you have multiple columns under a single column heading.

See the [documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_06.html) and [API](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/AdvancedDataGrid.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

DataGrid great way to show data.  AdvanceDataGrid great way to give yourself a headache.

Comment: funny comment. For simple data display, datagrid is enough.

Comment: ha not sure why my answer go down voted considering it's true.  The person has obviously not looked at the code behind the AdvancedDataGrid.

Answer (score 1):

1. With ADG you can group the data based on some grouping criteria but
   with DG you can't. Also there is concept of Grouped Columns and Grouped item renderers in ADG
2. With ADG you can display the hierarchical data.
3. ADG provides a multicolumn sorting which DG doesn't.